# How to retrieve pip requirements (freeze) within Python?

Tags: python, pip, freeze

I posted this question on the git issue tracker: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2969

Can we have some manner of calling pip freeze/list within python, i.e. not a shell context?

I want to be able to import pip and do something like requirements = pip.freeze(). Calling pip.main(['freeze']) writes to stdout, doesn't return str values.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There's a pip.operation.freeze in newer releases (>1.x):

```
try: from pip._internal.operations import freeze
except ImportError: # pip < 10.0
    from pip.operations import freeze

pkgs = freeze.freeze()
for pkg in pkgs: print(pkg)
```

Output is, as expected:

> amqp==1.4.6
> anyjson==0.3.3
> billiard==3.3.0.20
> defusedxml==0.4.1
> Django==1.8.1
> django-picklefield==0.3.1
> docutils==0.12
> ... etc

Comment: For those that want all the packages in a variable (instead of printing directly), this will work well: `x = "\n".join(list(freeze.freeze()))`

Comment: Despite this being the accepted answer, Zak and sedeh make a very valid point in their answers. Relying on internals is risky, as the implementation may change.

Answer (score 14):

The other answers here are unsupported by pip: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program

According to pip developers:

> If you're directly importing pip's internals and using them, that isn't a supported usecase.

try

```
reqs = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'freeze'])
```

Answer (score 10):

It's not recommended to rely on a "private" function such as `pip._internal.operatons`. You can do the following instead:

```
import pkg_resources
env = dict(tuple(str(ws).split()) for ws in pkg_resources.working_set)
```

Comment: Like this solution the best. However, instead of relying on the string representation it's probably safer to do something like this `installed = {pkg.key: pkg.version for pkg in pkg_resources.working_set}`

Comment: `pkg_resources` is deprecated now, so I suggested an alternative through `importlib.metadata` as a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually from [`pip >= 10.0.0`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#deprecations-and-removals) package `operations.freeze` has moved to `pip._internal.operations.freeze`.

So the safe way to import `freeze` is:

```
try:
    from pip._internal.operations import freeze
except ImportError:
    from pip.operations import freeze
```

Answer (score 0):

To build off of sedeh and Marvin's answers above, I found an as_requirements() method, so this worked for me to get the almost equivalent of pip freeze.

```
excluded_packages = ['wheel', 'setuptools', 'pip']
modules = [str(p.as_requirement()) for p in pkg_resources.working_set if p and p.key not in excluded_packages]
```

The only other issue I had was 'typing-extensions' vs 'typing_extensions'.  Both seem to pip install so doesn't appear to be a big issue.

Comment: `pkg_resources` is deprecated now, so I suggested an alternative through `importlib.metadata` as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not recommended to rely on a private function such as `pip._internal.operatons` and also `pkg_resources` suggested as an alternative is now deprecated, I suggest using `importlib.metadata` instead.

```
from importlib import metadata

dists = metadata.distributions()
for dist in dists:
    name = dist.metadata["Name"]
    version = dist.version
    print(name, version)
```