# Get Django Project requirements (pip packages installed) in Pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm trying to get, without success, the requirements.txt from the virtual environment I created in [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) for a Django Project.
My Pycharm version is 2016.2, Django 1.10.3 and Python 3.5.1.

I want something like (example if I just had Django installed):

```
Django==1.10.3
```

#### First attempt:

Using Python Console - Didn't work because it automatically runs the Django shell instead. I've even tried changing the starting script in the Settings but the Django console is always opened instead of the Python one.

#### Second attempt:

Using the Terminal - Didn't work because it appears I don't have any virtual environment (doing `lsvirtualenv` gives an empty list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that this is a common problem, already discussed [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206603015-Can-pycharm-create-the-requirements-txt-file-what-am-I-missing-).

As you can see from the discussion the values are easily obtained with `pip freeze` for the `virtualenv` is giving problems and so I solved this problem with the help of [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31304042/4470542) using the same approach as the **First Attempt**.

1. Disabled Django support (Settings -> Languages & Framework -> Django)
2. Open the Python Console (Tools -> Python Console)
3. Do:

   ```
   from pip.operations import freeze
   x = freeze.freeze()
   for p in x:
       print (p)
   ```

You may copy the response content to `requirements.txt` or change the script above to save the requirements directly to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't have `virtualenvwrapper` installed? `workon` is a `virtualenvwrapper` command, not a `virtualenv` command. You can either install `virtualenvwrapper` and use `workon` or try using `virtualenv`'s command like this:

`source /path_to_your_virtualenv/bin/activate`

If you do have `virtualenvwrapper`, then you can create a virtual environment using `mkvirtualenv -p <your_python> <your_env_name>` and use it inside PyCharm going to `preferences` > `Project interpreter`.

Comment: I have it installed. The problem is with the absence of environments, not with the install of virtualenvwrapper

Comment: If you have the environment in PyCharm, it means it exists somewhere and that you should be able to access it from the outside. In PyCharm, try going to `preferences` and search for `Project interpreter`. You should see a list of the existent interpreters and the packages installed in those, which is the equivalent of doing `pip freeze` inside a virtual environment.